# Trying to define relationship between two numbers

Tags: relations

I have 2 numbers 97 (F) and 415 (S) this is the key / legend.

Given any number (S), commonly between 200 - 900, I am looking for "F".

Where if (S) is above 415 "F" will be less than 97 and if (S) is below 415 "F" will be more than 97.

- The higher "S" is the lower "F" is.
- The lower "S" is the higher "F" is.

Here's some estimations:

- 415 (S) gives 97 (F)
- 612 (S) should give ~72 (F)
- 514 (S) should give ~82 (F)

This is not a standard proportion as (F) of 612 (S) would be higher than 97.

What is this relationship called? How can I find the "F" of any number (S)?

Comment: So, you are looking for a function $F = f(S)$, increasing on $S\in(200, 900)$, such that $f(415) = 97, f(514) = 82$, and $f(612) = 72$? Any number of functions have these properties. The "simplest" function I can think of at the moment is a quadratic.

Comment: If the relation is a polynomial, you can use the [Lagrange Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) on a finite set of data values. If you have enough data, the interpolated polynomial will be the polynomial you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I figured this out by doing this.

```
const getF = (S) => (1 / (S / 415)) * 97;
```